# Strange datagridview fill option in upper left corner

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2015, tabcontrol

I have a tab control, and one of the tab pages have a docked datagridview. In my designer everything looks fine, but when I run the program I see this..

[image]

and when I click on the corner, it fills the datagridview to the page just fine. I have tried docking left, right, bottom and top to no avail. I should mention I am using MetroUI tab control. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of messing around with the properties I figured out a solution. I restarted visual studio and it updated my designer, so that weird fill control was visible. I then was able to mess around with the datagridview and figured out that the issue was that it was overlapping my tab control. I moved the datagridview down just a tad and it works fine.